# Sharing partitions in qemu

Tags: linux, partition, kvm, qemu

Apart from networking and partition sharing I've made qemu work pretty much like I want it to. I've got a bit of a special setup, I need to pass through `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`. (Is it possible to passthrough `/dev/sda` without passing through `/dev/sda3` with it? I can live with using alternative methods.)

`/dev/sda` (MBR) = Windows Bootmgr on `/dev/sda1`

`/dev/sda1` = System Reserved partition (Windows's bootloader)

`/dev/sda2` = Windows 7's `C:/` partition

`/dev/sda3` = Arch Linux (Host)

I've got `/dev/sda3`'s grub installed into the MBR of `/dev/sdc` (meaning booting `/dev/sdc` will boot me into my arch Linux install, booting `/dev/sda` will boot me into Windows)
I will be passing through `/dev/sdc` as well but this one is easy as the host doesn't need any access to this drive after booting.

Finally I have a GPT, (NTFS) storage partition on `/dev/sdb2` that I want to be easily accessible from both the host and my guest at the same time (I want to share it between both systems)

How do I proceed with `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb2`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the device mapper to shape a device that contains the parts of the original device you want. For instance:

```
$ grep . /sys/class/block/sda/**/(size|start)
/sys/class/block/sda/sda1/size:224847
/sys/class/block/sda/sda1/start:63
/sys/class/block/sda/sda2/size:124820514
/sys/class/block/sda/sda2/start:224910
/sys/class/block/sda/size:125045424
```

If I want to *hide* `sda2`, I can create a `/dev/mapper/no_sda2` where sectors 224910 to 125045424 contain zeros:

- First create a loop device as otherwise dmsetup will complain because `/dev/sda` is in use (while `loop` will not complain which doesn't sound very consistent to me):

  ```
  losetup /dev/loop0 /dev/sda
  ```
- Then create `/dev/mapper/no_sda2` as:

  ```
  dmsetup create no_sda2 << EOF
  0 224910 linear /dev/loop0 0
  224910 $((125045424-224910)) zero
  EOF
  ```

Comment: this will allow me to mount /dev/mapper/no_sda2 on the VM and /dev/sda2 on the host and safely share the partitions between them?